# Is there a reliable way to measure performance of code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance

If you look a below code you will see measuring of performance of very simple for loop.

```
var res = 0;
function runs(){
    var a1 = performance.now();
    var x = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<10**9;i++) {
        x++;  
    }
    var a2 = performance.now();
    res += (a2-a1);
}

for(var j=0;j<10;j++){
    runs();
}
console.log(`=${res/10}`);
```

Additionally, just for a good measure, this will run 10 times and average results. Now, issue with this is that it is not reliable, it highly depends on your CPU, memory and other programs running on your device.
First time, may run 9s and second 23s, then subsequent call can result 8s.

Is there a way to measure performance regardless of CPU, memory and everything else?
I am after something that will give relative number of FLOPS or any other measure that when you compare two codes you will exactly know that one code executes faster than the other.

For instance `for` loop with 1005 will always show slower than one with 1000 iterations.

**Note:** Saying FLOPS is wrong in this context as it means - floating point operations per second.
I would like to exclude time completely, I only need FPOs. Meaning I do not care about seconds, just about reliably knowing that regardless of device if you have same code it will always take let say 2000 FPOs to execute.

Comment: I guess it is not that easy to achieve what you want with JS. It highly depends on executing the environment, version, and type of engine executing in. Even assuming you running your code only on V8 engine JIT compilation and run-time optimization could lead to slightly different results from time to time. You can have a counter to count the exact amount of iteration or so and it will be not time-related.

Comment: @DmitriiZolotuhin I get what you saying, but imagine that V8 and underlying software/browser is the same (or you can imagine it is just being a same machine). That being said is there a way to measure operations, I do not know using WebAPI, some browser or engine experimental options?

Comment: you can get objective relative measures by running it on an engine without optimization; either a debug-flagged V8 or an old browser like IE7,

Comment: I built an app measuring the performance of two different solutions and chart it out in a graph. ran on the same machine, it will output a trend.The trend will always be the same regardless of the CPU, browser, engine, machine. You could also calculate the BigO to understand the complexity of each function. If you want them to run always under a certain time limit, then not sure. Even on hackerrank, if u run a solution multiple times, you'll notice the same test sometimes passing, sometimes failing,because it gives different time restraint results I guess